Trouble generating large graph with auto-pst-pdf
I try to use latex packages auto-pst-pdf and psfrag to produce dot graphs that require latex labels. It works well with small examples (10 ~ 20 nodes). However, when the number of nodes gets larger (1k+ nodes), pdfLatex fails to produce the desired pdf files, with the error message File 'xxx-pics.pdf' not found. Strangely, pdfLatex outputs a file named xxx-autopp.pdf, and the content seems correct. I was wondering about the possible cause for the failure of pdfLatex to integrate the graph into the pdf file.
The way I compile the latex file:
pdflatex -shell-escape xxx.tex

The actual xxx.tex is quite large and contains thousands of lines so I could not post it here. But basically it has the following form:
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[psfrag]{graphviz}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\begin{document}
\psfrag{label0}[cc][cc]{$\mathcal{F}$}
...
\digraph{abc}{
...
}
\end{document}


